# body_class REST field in WP-API

Tags: api, json, rest-api, body-class

I'm building a site with WP-API (v2). I'm attempting to [add a REST field according to documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/) that includes anything from `body_class`.

However, `body_class` is returning either *one* class (one added by my theme) or *no* classes (when the condition in the theme that adds the class is false).

Here's the relevant code in my `api.php` file (included via `functions.php`).

```
// Obtain body classes
function bsd_get_body_class( $data, $object, $request ) {
  $classes = get_body_class();

  return $classes;
}

// Obtain post classes
function bsd_get_post_classes( $data, $post, $request ) {
  return get_post_class();
}

function bsd_rest_fields() {
  register_rest_field(['page', 'post'], 'body-class', array(
      'get_callback' => 'bsd_get_body_class'
    )
  );

  register_rest_field(['post'], 'post-classes', array(
    'get_callback' => 'bsd_get_post_classes'
    )
  );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'bsd_rest_fields', 15 );
```

The `post_classes` function works perfectly and I can access that data in my state; the `body_classes` does not, however.

Using `body_class` in other theme files works fine--the body classes are applied in, for instance, page templates.

It's interesting to note that doing `print_r(get_body_class())` inside my `functions.php` file also returns one (or zero) classes, but inside a template file, it works fine.

Comment: It looks like the `rest_api_init` action is called before the `$wp` object is instantiated, so I have to figure out how to hook the function into the `wp` action, I think, _inside_ the REST API callback.

Comment: If you look here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L545 you can see the conditions that add each of the classes.

Comment: @czerspalace Yes, the conditions (and filters in my theme) are fine--what I'm trying to do is add the classes to a field in the REST API. However, the API hook `rest_api_init` appears to fire before the `$wp` object is set up, so my callback (`bsd_get_body_class`) is returning an empty array. (At least, I think that's what's happening.)

Comment: Ahh ok. Which body classes were you expecting to be present? Or based on the link, which conditions did you expect to be true?

Comment: @czerspalace All of them, haha. But the array is empty (or just contains the class added in my theme). I think my solution will be to add the results of get_body_class as post meta to my posts/pages, and then use the API to access the meta, rather than the function `get_body_class`. That seems like the easiest/cleanest way to do it.

Comment: @czerspalace Answer below, if you're curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_body_class()` relies on `$wp_query` to do its thing, which is apparently a no-go for the JSON API.

I considered creating a global object to hold the body class, and just using that to keep the `body_class` up to date...but that wouldn't work without page reloads, and there would be no assurance that the object was up-to-date.

The only way I could get it to remotely work was by hijacking the main `$wp_query` object, which is a no-no.

The semi-working code looked something like:

```
function bsd_get_body_class($id) {
  global $wp_query;
  $wp_query = $orig_query;

  $new_query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $id, 'post_type' => 'any' ) );

  $wp_query = $new_query;
  $classes = get_body_class();

  wp_reset_postdata(); 

  $wp_query = $old_query;

  return $classes;
} 

// Add $classes as a REST field to the API according to docs
```

Even then, though, `$classes` didn't necessarily match the output of `body_class()` inside my template files, I think because it happened earlier in the query than in the templates.

So I scrapped it.

I ended up writing a simple class builder in JS that re-creates some of the WP functionality, instead of using the API and storing the classes in my app's state. It looks like this:

```
export const bodyClass = (data) => {
  var classes = [];

  if (data['id'] && data['type'])
    classes.push(data['type'] + '-id-' + data['id']);
  if (data['type'])
    classes.push(data['type']);
  if (data['is-front-page'] === true)
    classes.push('home')
  else
    classes.push('internal');

  return classes;
}
```

If somebody out there knows a good way to get presentational data from the WP API, I'm all ears, but after days of hacking, I couldn't find a reliable, consistent way to get the classes out of `$wp_query`. (`post_classes`, on the other hand, works like a charm.)